# Can't display the embedded Blackthorn form

Tags: iframe, salesforce

Our organization uses Blackthorn (in Salesforce) for event registration. We created the Blackthorn form and then we need to embed the form in one page on our website. We use IIS as the web server.

I have added our server's domain to Blackthorn via the `Manage Existing Domains` page. However, we still got error when loading the page that contains an embedded form through iframe:

```
Refused to frame 'https://events.blackthorn.io/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' https://*.salesforce.com https://*.salesforce-communities.com https://*.visualforce.com https://*.force.com https://*.my.site.com https://*.salesforce-experience.com https://myorganization.cdn.salesforce-experience.com https://payments.blackthorn.io https://events.blackthorn.io".
```

Here is how the page looks like with the error described above):

[image]

My question is where I should work on to fix it and how to fix this problem.

Comment: I got the same issue but adding domain in the Allowlist Domains solved my problem. make sure your domain is added there and is https. Here is my code that I used.

<div class="calendar-integration-wrap">
        <script src="https://events.blackthorn.io/loader" data-path="0000000000/0/000000"></script>
    </div>

where 0000 in data-path replaced by your data-path.

Comment: Thanks for help! In my case, I had to contact Blackthorn support and they did some work on their side, in addition to whitelisting domains.